# Real Analysis sequence proof issues

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I recently showed a few proofs to a professor at my school, he said that there were logical issues with my proofs and that I should stick more closely to the text book examples when constructing proofs. But he never specified exactly what aspects of the proofs needed work, and left me with more questions than I started with.  Being new to proofs and Real Analysis I wanted to know which parts of my proofs are weak or wrong so I can do better in the future.  Both of the proofs are on sequences.
I would like to know which parts of my proofs are not working and which parts are good. I am a self study student and don't really have a gauge on how I'm doing in my proofs. Any advice, tips, or things to change are welcomed.

---

> Let $a_n=7-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  Show that $a_n\to7$ as $n\to \infty$.

Setup work:
$|a_n-a|<\epsilon\Rightarrow\left|7-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-7\right|<\epsilon\Rightarrow\left|-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right|<\epsilon\Rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$.
Solving for $n$ where $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\epsilon$ ,
$n=\large\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$.

*Proof.*
Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Set $N=1/\epsilon^2$, now for any $n > N$,
$|a_n-a|<\epsilon=|7-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -7|<\epsilon$ implying that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, now substituting $N$ into the equation $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ produces $\large\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}}}\Rightarrow\large\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$=$\epsilon$.
Thus by definition 3.7 as $n\to\infty $, $a_n \to 7$.
$\mathbb{\square}$

Definition 3.7.  A sequence ($a_n$) converges to $a\in \mathbb{R}$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$

---

> Let ($a_n$) be a bounded sequence, and consider a second sequence ($b_n$) defined by $b_n$ := sup{$a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},...$}. Prove that ($b_n$) converges.

*Proof.*

Since $a_n$ is defined as a bounded sequence, the supremum of $a_n$ exists, meaning $\sup\{a_n\}=U$ where $U\in \mathbb{R}$.   Now for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the value of $\sup\{a_n\}$ will remain constant or increase, implying that $\sup\{a_n\}\leq \sup\{a_{n+1}\}$.

Since $b_n$ is defined as $b_n=\sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},\dots\}$, The value of $b_n$ will also remain constant or increase, that is, $b_n \leq b_{n+1}$ implying that $b_n$ is a monotone sequence and is bounded, thus by the monotone convergence theorem $b_n$ converges for all $n$.

$\mathbb{\square}$

Comment: First proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$ and set $N=1/\epsilon^2$ then for any $n>N$,  $|a_n-7|=|-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|<|\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}|=\epsilon$. Your proof had an un-necessary $\epsilon$ in there. Pretty good but maybe looked a bit unsure and overdone. Start with $|a_n-a|$ in this kind of proof and finish on $\epsilon$

Comment: Your solution to the first problem is very scrambled: "$|a_n-a|<\epsilon$... implying..." is simply backwards - you're starting with what you want and showing it implies something, which is simply not what's required.

Comment: @Paul "Start with $|a_n-a|$ and finish on $\epsilon$" may be great advice regarding how to _find_ a proof. But _presenting_ the proof that way is simply wrong; backwards.

Comment: For a correct solution see the almost identical example in the book. **Note** how in that example the $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ is a _conclusion_, not something we say implies other things...

Comment: @David. C. Ulrich I was briefly trying to say that once you start with the thing you are trying to estimate (after the preamble with $\epsilon$ and N) your $\epsilon$ should appear once at the end is all.

Comment: You first proof makes no sense.  You set $N=\frac 1\{e^2}$. Fine so we need to prove that if $n > N$ then $|(7-\frac 1{\sqrt n}) -7| < \epsilon$.  THen you .... just state it without proof.  Are you assuming you proved it in the setup?  If so you are done.  When you get $|(7-\frac 1{\sqrt n}) - 7| < \epsilon$ then !!!!STOP!!!! YOU ARE DONE!!!! But otherwise must prove it.

Answer (score 2):

The first proof... It looks like you are manipulating the symbols to get $\epsilon$, but you are forgetting that you are supposed to prove what is essentially just an *inequality*. Namely, from $n\gt N=\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ you need to prove $|a_n-7|\lt\epsilon$. Now, if $n\gt N$, you can conclude:

$$|a_n-7|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\color{red}{\lt}\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}=\epsilon$$

(the first equality you have shown correctly in your proof). I find a fault not just that your inequality sign was wrong ($\gt$ rather than $\lt$) but that you didn't seem to even care what the sign will be. Remember, the point is not to express/calculate $\epsilon$ from the given data, the point is to prove that something is/can be made *smaller* than $\epsilon$.

As for the second proof, it is incorrect as it incorrectly captures what is happening with those suprema. Imagine you make some set *smaller*: what do you expect to happen with its supremum/infimum? Answer: the supremum goes *down* and the infimum goes *up*. In our case the sets $\{a_n, a_{n+1}, a_{n+2},\ldots\}$ are getting *smaller* all the time: the next set is obtained by *throwing away* $a_n$ from the previous set. Thus, the sequence $b_n$ will be *decreasing*. (It will still be bounded from below, so you would still be able to apply the monotone convergence theorem.)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I notice is , $N=1/ϵ^2$ , in fact N is an integer you can take for example $N=floor(1/ϵ^2)+1$

Secondly , the variable $a$ that you included doesn't refer to anything already defined .